# how to handle downloaded media files in chat app above android 10

Tags: java, android, chat

i am creating a chat app that downloads & saves media files in specific chat app folder using getExternalStorageDirectory() and saves its uri path in sqlite to access offline within chat app  and sends uri path to server(in case if users uninstall and reinstall my app) in below android 10.

my question is - am i following the right approach to save media files?and if my approach is right then how can i do the same in above android 10 because getExternalStorageDirectory() is deprecated.

Comment: "am i following the right approach to save media files?" -- IMHO, no. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the *user* choose where on the *user's* device that the *user* wants you to store the *user's* content.

Comment: @CommonsWare don't you think ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE gives huge inconvenience for user experience.especially,half of my target audience are senior citizens.i really appreciate if you guide me to any other solution.

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` is simply the Android equivalent of the "choose directory" dialogs that desktop operating systems have had for decades. I do not recall hearing that such dialogs are a "huge inconvenience" for users, regardless of their age. Bear in mind that you only need to show `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` once in most cases. You would use `takePersistableUriPermission()` and save that tree `Uri` for long-term use.

Comment: @CommonsWare In non English speaking countries it's a big deal.most of the senior citizen from developing countries(from villages)are never used desktop but adopted minimal usage of smart phone.they use apps with repeated behaviors.are other chat apps like WhatsApp uses ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE type of behavior.

Comment: Your choices are: use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` (and take this opportunity to educate your users), use `MediaStore` (to store the media in traditional media locations), or use `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context` (and live with the fact that if the user installs and reinstalls the app that you would need to download that media again).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your comment.i will look for the MediaStore.

Comment: See https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html for the first `MediaStore` post in a series of scoped storage posts.